# Chat UI in ionic 3

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass

I have tried to create a chat UI. I’m having the trouble with the placement of chat bubbles. It is as
[image]

This is my HTML code

```html
<ion-list no-lines class="msgbubble" *ngFor="let msg of messages">
    <div class="innermsg left" *ngIf="userId != msg.id">
      {{ msg.reply }}
    </div>
    <div class="innermsg right" *ngIf="userId == msg.id">
        {{ msg.reply }}
    </div>
</ion-list>
```

This is my scss code

```css
.innermsg {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        margin: 5px;
        font-weight: 500;
        font-size: 16px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .innermsg.left {
        float: left;
        background-color: #F1F0F0;
        color: black;
    }

    .innermsg.right {
        float: right;
        //margin-right: 10%;
        background-color: #0084FF;
        color: white;
    }

    .msgbubble {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

Can someone help me in displaying chat bubbles on after the another, but not in the same line as shown in above picture.

Comment: isn't any of the answers working for you? Please accept an answer or give comments of the issue still faced.

Comment: nope I've not got the the perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

The HTML structure needs to change a bit, each chat bubble needs to take up a line and only the contents inside the line must have the formatting you have.

Like this:

```
  <ion-list no-lines class="msgbubble" >
    <ion-item *ngFor="let msg of messages">
      <span [ngClass]="userId == msg.id ? 'innermsg right':'innermsg left'">{{ msg.reply }}</span>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Check the implementation [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-bk5mc3?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox, `flex-direction: column`, and give each person differing `align-self` values.

In Angular I think the syntax for the element would be:

```
<div [ngClass]="userId === msg.id ? 'me' : 'you'">{{msg.reply}}</div>
```

Here's an example with static elements:

```css
.chat {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.message {
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0.2em 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.me {
  align-self: flex-start;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.you {
  align-self: flex-end;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat">
  <div class="message me">Hello</div>
  <div class="message you">Hello</div>
  <div class="message me">How are you?</div>
  <div class="message you">I'm fine</div>
  <div class="message you">How about you?</div>
  <div class="message me">I'm doing so amazingly you wouldn't believe all the things that are happening right now it would take up at least 50% of the width of the page to discuss all the things that I want to tell you.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code for my chat app that I've been working on. You may be able to have some use from it.

```
<ion-list>
  <div text-right *ngFor="let message of messages; let i = index; let first = first;">

    <div *ngIf = "message.from == this.user">

        <span *ngIf = "i==0" > 
            <ion-label stacked> {{message?.from}} </ion-label>
          <p text-right> {{message?.msg}}</p>
        </span>

        <span *ngIf = "i>0 && message.from == messages[i-1].from" > 
          <p text-right> {{message?.msg}}</p>
        </span>

        <span *ngIf = "i>0 && message.from != messages[i-1].from" > 
            <ion-label stacked> {{message?.from}} </ion-label>
          <p text-right> {{message?.msg}}</p>
        </span>

    </div>

    <div *ngIf = "message.from != this.user">

        <span *ngIf = "i==0" > 
            <ion-label stacked text-left> {{message?.from}} </ion-label>
          <p text-left> {{message?.msg}}</p>
        </span>

        <span *ngIf = "i>0 && message.from == messages[i-1].from" > 
          <p text-left> {{message?.msg}}</p>
        </span>

        <span *ngIf = "i>0 && message.from != messages[i-1].from" > 
            <ion-label stacked text-left> {{message?.from}} </ion-label>
          <p text-left> {{message?.msg}}</p>
        </span>

    </div>


  </div>
</ion-list>
```